# hbase-master fails to start

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to set up a Hadoop development environment. I am using CDH4 and following the installation instructions in their website https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/.

I got to the point in which I was able to install CDH4 in pseudo-distributed mode and I am following the part regarding "Components that require additional configuration".

I have installed HBase-master package, but when I try to start the service I am getting the following error:

```
$ sudo /sbin/service hbase-master start
starting master, logging to /var/log/hbase/hbase-hbase-master-slc01euu.out
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/PlatformName
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName. Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable
```

I suposse that it has something to do with some env variable (i believe HADOOP_HOME). But I am not sure where to look at since all the previous processes (name node, data node, job tracker,task tracker) started with no problem.

When I search for HADOOP_HOME variable it says that it is undefined.

Do you guys have any idea about how I could solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the scripts starting the hbase master and/or set the environment variable in your shell. Or just set the variable before starting the service and check if this is the real problem.

Comment: @user2162926 Try to have a look at the hbase script where `HADOOP_IN_PATH` is set. What do you get if you issue _which hadoop_ ?

Comment: Are you using Hadoop 2.2 ? I think it's a classpath problem (a missing jar hadoop-core maybe)

Answer (score 0):

Please set HADOOP_HOME to your hadoop installation directory
eg: export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hadoop

Add a pointer to your HADOOP_CONF_DIR to the HBASE_CLASSPATH environment variable in hbase-env.sh.

Add a copy of hdfs-site.xml (and core-site.xml) in under ${HBASE_HOME}/conf folder